# Why is "zero (deleted)" using so much memory?

Tags: php, linux

I'm running CloudLinux 7. I keep getting LFD notifications like the following:

```
Time:         Thu Sep  1 16:29:12 2016 -0400
Account:      xxx
Resource:     Virtual Memory Size
Exceeded:     1226 > 256 (MB)
Executable:   /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/bin/lsphp.cagefs
Command Line: lsphp
PID:          102817 (Parent PID:102817)
Killed:       No
```

I created a test.php with the code `sleep(30);` and used `pmap` to track its memory use. The following is the output  (truncated):

```
Address           Kbytes     RSS   Dirty Mode  Mapping
00007f68183e7000 1048576     132     132 rw-s- zero (deleted)
00007f68583e7000      48       0       0 r-x-- libnss_files-2.17.so
00007f68583f3000    2044       0       0 ----- libnss_files-2.17.so
00007f68585f2000       4       4       4 r---- libnss_files-2.17.so
00007f68585f3000       4       4       4 rw--- libnss_files-2.17.so
00007f68585f4000      24       0       0 rw---   [ anon ]
00007f68585fa000      28      20       0 r-x-- xmlreader.so
00007f6858601000    2044       0       0 ----- xmlreader.so
---------------- ------- ------- -------
total kB         1256296    9228    6340
```

It looks like the most RAM is being used by that first line item -- `zero (deleted)`. Looking around, that is shared memory... but why is it so high? How much I lower it?